# Correctly filling up multidimensional array

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to fill an multidimensional array with data from an SQL database. Because there isn't an function like myarray.Add for this I figured out something else. But it is not working! I'm using C# .net 
The following line is giving errors: arr[counter2] = {myDataReader["rating"], myDataReader["date"]};

```
public string[,] getData(int id)
    {


        string queryString = "SELECT rating, date FROM rating WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
        SqlDataReader myDataReader = Database.sqlDataReader(queryString);

        if (myDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                counter++;
            }
            string[,] arr = new string[counter, 2];
            int counter2 = 0;
            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                counter2++;
                arr[counter2] = {myDataReader["rating"], myDataReader["date"]};
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

Could someone help me fix this or explain me another (and probably better) way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want the data to go to an array rather than a DataTable?

Comment: Are your `rating` and `date` database columns both string types (such as `varchar`)?

Answer (score 3):

That's overly complicated. Try this:

```
public string[,] getData(int id)
{        
    string queryString = "SELECT rating, date FROM rating WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
    List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

    using(SqlDataReader myDataReader = Database.sqlDataReader(queryString))       
        while(myDataReader.Read())        
            data.Add(new int[] { (string)myDataReader["rating"], (string)myDataReader["date"] });

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

Plus, you really shouldn't concatenate your SQL statement.

Comment: @Justin Yeah, have no idea where those `int`s came from.

Comment: I changed it to string[] but at `data.ToArray();` i'm getting this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'string[*,*]'

Answer (score 1):

Either use a jagged array:

```
public string[][] getData(int id)
...
string[][] arr = new string[counter][];
...
arr[counter2] = new string[] {myDataReader["rating"], myDataReader["date"]};
```

Or assign each entry individually:

```
arr[counter2,0] = myDataReader["rating"];
arr[counter2,1] = myDataReader["date"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayLists in an ArrayList
It is better for database results because they are dynamic (no need to declare size).
See the following post:
[Multi-dimensional arraylist or list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596530/multi-dimensional-arraylist-or-list-in-c)