# multiple arraylist repeat subjectname display in sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Answer in c# also help me.

I tried this code for if i have duplicate string in multiple arraylist it update and display in sequence as before.

```
maths
english
maths
hindi
english
science
Economics
scince
```

i need output like this

```
maths_1
english_1
maths_2
hindi
science_1
Economics
scince_2
```

i tried this code but output is not in sequence**

```
Dim subjectCounts As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
            For Each subject As String In arraysub
                If subjectCounts.ContainsKey(subject) Then
                    subjectCounts(subject) = (subjectCounts(subject) + 1)
                Else
                    subjectCounts.Add(subject, 1)
                End If
            Next
            Dim output As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

            For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In subjectCounts
                If (pair.Value > 1) Then
                    Dim i As Integer = 1
                    Do While (i <= pair.Value)
                        output.Add((i.ToString + ("_" + pair.Key)))

                        i = (i + 1)
                    Loop
                Else
                    output.Add(pair.Key)
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why did you flag this with C# and asp.net? And wat do you mean by not in sequence?

Comment: Answer in c# also help me.

Comment: my subjectname is in arraylist so if i have two subject with same name then i want to update that arraylist.but sequence of arraylist is not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this generates the output you want

First let us check if the subject need to have the "_#" ending

now we run throught the subject, and add the _# ending for 
everyone that has more then one occurence.
The order will be the same as the input, since we run through it. 
The counting will generated on the fly, so this will be correct.

```
    Dim hasMultiple As New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)
    For Each subject As String In arraysub
        If hasMultiple.ContainsKey(subject) Then
            hasMultiple(subject) =  True
        Else
            hasMultiple.Add(subject, False)
        End If
    Next

    Dim output As New List(Of String)
    Dim subCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) 
    For Each subject As String In arraysub
        If Not subCount.ContainsKey(subject) Then
            subCount.Add(subject, 0)
        End If
        subCount(subject) += 1
        If hasMultiple(subject) Then
            output.Add(subject & "_" & subCount(subject))
        Else
            output.Add(subject)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in using a dictionary.  dictionaries aren't ordered so there's no guarantee of the order whenever you iterate through it.  However a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String,Integer))` will do the job you want.

Additionally you can do it using the same list(Of String).  I don't use arraylist's much, never found a need that a list can't do, but I imagine the syntax should be pretty much the same.  Something like this should work

```
Dim arraysub As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)({
"maths",
"english",
"maths",
"hindi",
"english",
"science",
"Economics",
"science"
})
For i = 0 To arraysub.Count - 1
    If Not Char.IsDigit(arraysub(i).Last) Then
        Dim temp As String = arraysub(i)
        For j = 0 To arraysub.FindAll(Function(s) s = arraysub(i)).Count - 1
            arraysub(arraysub.IndexOf(temp)) += "_" + (j + 1).ToString
        Next
    End If
Next
```

The output is:

```
?arraysub
Count = 8
    (0): "maths_1"
    (1): "english_1"
    (2): "maths_2"
    (3): "hindi_1"
    (4): "english_2"
    (5): "science_1"
    (6): "Economics_1"
    (7): "science_2"
```

Here's the same code using an arraylist:

```
    Dim arraysub As ArrayList = New ArrayList(New String(7) {"maths", "english", "maths", "hindi", "english", "science", "Economics", "science"})
    For i = 0 To arraysub.Count - 1
        If Not Char.IsDigit(CStr(arraysub(i)).Last) Then
            Dim temp As String = CStr(arraysub(i))
            For j = 0 To Array.FindAll(arraysub.ToArray, Function(s) s Is CStr(arraysub(i))).Count - 1
                arraysub(arraysub.IndexOf(temp)) = CStr(CStr(arraysub(arraysub.IndexOf(temp))) & "_" + (j + 1).ToString)
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

and has this output:

```
?arraysub
Count = 8
    (0): "maths_1" {String}
    (1): "english_1" {String}
    (2): "maths_2" {String}
    (3): "hindi_1" {String}
    (4): "english_2" {String}
    (5): "science_1" {String}
    (6): "Economics_1" {String}
    (7): "science_2" {String}
```

you can see from this why many people prefer List over ArrayList.

Comment: i don't want two array list.I want to update the array in same arraylist .. I want full code.

Comment: Using this list replaces the dictionary and doesn't add an extra collection.

Comment: my subjectname is in arraylist so if i have two subject with same name then i want to update that arraylist.but sequence of arraylist is not change

Comment: sir i using ur code but it gives me error msg   FindAll is not member of arraylist

Comment: Findall is method of arraylist or not?

Comment: I am very near to answer just give me answer Findall is not  member of system.collection.arraylist?

Comment: Arraylists are so awkward to use I had to juggle the code a bit.  But got a working answer for you.

Comment: sir if i remove last from arraysub(i).last then all subject append _1 if write arraysub(i).last it gives me error last is not string

Comment: It was in there for a reason.  Why would you remove it?

Comment: because it gives me error that last is not string so i remove

Comment: last isn't a string its a character and it's used as a character.  How and why are you changing it to use it as a string?  Why did you ask for full code if you're going to change things willy nilly?

Comment: this line  If Not Char.IsDigit(CStr(arraysub(i)).Last) Then gives me error

Comment: Did you copy and paste or type it in?  If you typed it in check all the parentheses and make sure you didn't miss any.  If you copied and pasted try it again just in case it didn't work right the first time.  That code wasn't just thrown together, its tested and works 100% like you asked.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the arraylist.  Would you be able to change it to a List and use the first code?

Comment: sir i want to use of arraylist so i use arraylist please sir i need help i m very near to logic

Comment: Did you make sure to copy the second set of code I gave you?  As you can see I used an arraylist and it works, so there must be something different on your end.  But since I'm not there it's gonna be kind of hard for me to see what the difference is.

Comment: .ok sir u give me ur code.i copy paste it.i m sure something miss by my side.

Comment: Also my code is designed to replace everything in your original post.

Comment: still not work  it gives error on two statements    For j = 0 To Array.FindAll(arraysub.ToArray, Function(s) s Is CStr(arraysub(i))).count and CStr(arraysub(i)).Last not support

Comment: How are you loading arraysub?  Is every value a string?

Comment: Dim arraysub As New ArrayList

            For i As Integer = 0 To Grd.Columns.Count - 1
                If Grd.Columns(i).Visible = True Then
                    arraysub.Add(RemoveHtmltag(GvSearch.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text))
                End If
            Next and all values are string. i add the value of headertext in arraylist

Comment: Is the return type of `RemoveHtmltag` a string?

Comment: its  string i m just using for remove html tags with this function

Comment: Was just looking at your tags, didn't see that you're using VS2008.  I'll fire mine up and see what I can do.

Comment: The only thing I had to change was how the arraylist was loaded and my code worked perfectly in VS2008 Express.  The only thing I can come up with is if you didn't explicitly declare the return type for `RemoveHtmltag ` the system might not be able to tell if it's a string.` Function RemoveHtmltag(ByVal Input As String) As String`

Comment: I'm at a loss then.  The only 2 courses of action I can see is to examine arraysub in the debugger and see if there is anything in there you don't expect.  Also to compare character by character, what's in your project with what I put in here.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596530/multi-dimensional-arraylist-or-list-in-c) post by [Charles Bretana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32632/charles-bretana)

Create class like this,

```
     public class MultiDimDictList<K, T>: Dictionary<K, List<T>>  
       {
           public void Add(K key, T addObject)
           {
               if(!ContainsKey(key)) 
               {
               Add(key, new List<T>());
               base[key].Add(addObject);
               }else{
               for(int i=1; i<i+1;i++){
                if(!ContainsKey(key+"_"+i)){
                    Add(key+"_"+i+, new List<T>());
                    base[key+"_"+i].Add(addObject+"_"+i);       
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }  
           }           
       }
```

call it like below,

```
myDicList.Add("YourKEY", "YourSUBJECT");
```

I just modified as per your requirement,  but i'm not sure about this.