# C# Converting List to 2d list and adding additional values

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

Hello need some assistance with this issue.  Hopefully i can describe it well.

I have a parser that goes though a document and find sessionID's, strips some tags from them and places them into a list.

```
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match sID = sessionId.Match(line);
                if (sID.Success)
                {
                    String sIDString;
                    String sid = sID.ToString();
                    sIDString = Regex.Replace(sid, "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
                    sessionIDList.Add(sIDString);
                }
            }
```

Then I go thought list and get the distinctSessionID's.

```
    List<String> distinctSessionID = sessionIDList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Now I need to go thought he document again and add the lines that match the sessionID and add them to the list.  This is the part that I am having issue with.

Do I need to create a 2d list so I can add the matching log lines to the corresponding sessionids.

I was looking at this but cannot seem to figure out a way that I could copy over my Distinct list then add the Lines I need into the new array.

From what I can test it looks like this would add the value into the masterlist

```
List<List<string>> masterLists = new List<List<string>>();
 Foreach (string value in distinctSessionID)
{
  masterLists[0].Add(value);
}
```

How do I add Lines I need to the corresponding Masterlist.  Say masterList[0].Add value is 1, how do i add the lines to 1?

```
          masterList[0][0].add(myLInes);
```

Basically i want

```
    Sessionid1
        -------> related log line
        -------> Related log line 
   SessionID2 
        -------> related log line
        -------> related log line.
```

So on and so forth.  I have the parsing all working, it's just getting the values into a 2nd string list is the issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, simple create a class with public properties, and make list of that custom class.

```
public class Session
{
  public int SessionId{get;set;}
  public List<string> SessionLog{get;set;}
}

List<Session> objList = new List<Session>();

var session1 = new Session();
session1.SessionId = 1;
session1.SessionLog.Add("description lline1");

objList.Add(session1);
```

Comment: Session 1 can have multiple entries though.  How would i incorporate that when I am adding?

Comment: Also the session ID can be a number or a number and string.  So SessionID will need to be a string.

Comment: So i changed it to a string for the SessionID.  Howerver, when I am testing session1.SessionLog.Add("description lline1"); I keep on getting a NullReferenceException. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Add  session1.SessionLog = new List<string>(); after session1.SessionId = 1;

Comment: Last question.  How would I add multiple to session1.SessionLog.add ?  This is how i have it, but it always seems to be writing to index zero for The session log.  It's the correct session DI but not log. objList[0].SessionLog.add("test1");  objList[0].SessionLog.add("test2");

Comment: I'll just ask a new question since it's changed.

Comment: Sorry I just opened stackoverflow, Is your work done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
 public class MultiDimDictList: Dictionary<string, List<int>>  { }
 MultiDimDictList myDictList = new MultiDimDictList ();
 Foreach (string value in distinctSessionID)
{
     myDictList.Add(value, new List<int>()); 
     for(int j=0; j < lengthofLines; j++)
     {
         myDictList[value].Add(myLine);
     }
}
```

You would need to replace `lengthofLines` with a number to indicate how many iterations of lines you have.

See Charles Bretana's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596530/multi-dimensional-arraylist-or-list-in-c)