# Alternate to 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I have to store two types of information in any data structure for what I came up with the scrap solution of 2D array in C#. I have to store as:

- *number of cluster* in `int` data type
- *cluster membership count* in `int` data type

If I use a 2D array as:

```
Int32[,] _clusterMembership = new Int32[10, 10];
```

But the issue here is:

- I don't know what total *number of cluster* will be?
- I don't know what *number of members* each cluster will have?

So the question is: 
*How can I manage to store this information in C# ?*

**ADDENDUM**
I have to use answer from this question here in this method as:

```
   public static List<Cluster> DP_Cluster(List<string> _customer, double _alpha)
    {
        var _currentClusters = 0;     // current number of clusters i.e. "k"
        var _memberNumber = 0;    // running member number i.e. "n"
        //var _dic = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
        var _probOld = 0.0;
        var _probNew = 0.0;


        List<Cluster> myClusters = new List<Cluster>();
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster(_currentClusters += 1);
        cluster.Members.Add(new ClusterMember { Name = _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber) });
        myClusters.Add(cluster);

        //_dic.Add(_currentClusters, _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber));
        _currentClusters += 1;

        for(int _i = 1; _i < _customer.Count - 1; _i++)
        {
            if( _i <= _currentClusters)
            {
                _probOld = myClusters[_i].Members.Count / ((_i+1) - 1 + _alpha);
            }
            else
            {
                _probNew = _alpha / ((_i+1) - 1 + _alpha);
            }

            if(_probNew > _probOld)
            {
                // Add _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber+=1) to New Cluster
                Cluster cluster = new Cluster( _currentClusters += 1 ); // Here is an error as we defining same name for another cluster
                myClusters.Add(cluster);
            }
            else
            {
                // Add _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber+=1) to Old Cluster
            }
        }

        return myClusters;
    }
```

- *How should I update my method to get desired results?*

Comment: It sounds like you should really have a `Cluster` data type with a `Members` property, then just create a `List<Cluster>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider making two types, one for the clusters and one for the members:

**Members**

```
public class ClusterMember
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    // more properties...
}
```

**Clusters**

```
public class Cluster
{
    public int ID {get;}
    public List<ClusterMember> Members {get;}
    public Cluster(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Members = new List<ClusterMember();
    }
}
```

And then you can store your clusters in a list

```
List<Cluster> myClusters = new List<Cluster>();
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(1);
cluster.Members.Add(new ClusterMember { Name = "Member1" });
myClusters.Add(cluster);
```

**UPDATE** I assumed that you want to do more with your data than just store these two information and tried to provide a better object-oriented approach.

To get your counts:

```
int totalNumberOfClusters = myClusters.Count;
int numberOfMembersInOneCluster = cluster.Members.Count;
int totalNumberOfClusterMembers = myClusters.Sum(c => c.Members.Count);
```

And to output the number of members for each cluster:

```
foreach(Cluster c in myClusters)
    Console.WriteLine($"Cluster {c.ID} has {c.Members.Count} members.");
```

Comment: He need to store only number and counts. Isnt he ?

Comment: @Rene--How can I get cluster number and number of members that cluster have i.e. memberCount for that cluster using your suggestion?

Comment: @erkandemir is saying right, I need to store as _cluster `x` has `a` members_, _cluster `y` has `b` members..._ and so on without knowing exact number of clusters and clusterMembers in advance

Comment: @maliks store your data in a dictionary<int,int>. you can get members count with cluster number. key = cluster number, value = members count

Comment: @maliks I just thought that storing these two information will not be the only thing you have to do with that data. In my solution, the final number of clusters is simply `myClusters.Count`, the number of members is `cluster.Members.Count` and the total member count could be `myClusters.Sum(c => c.Members.Count)`.

Comment: @RenéVogt I have added some **ADDENDUM** to my question. Please suggest me what to edit in my code accordingly

Comment: @RenéVogt Should we have to assign each `Cluster` class object a new name each time when a new _cluster_ is to be created ? As you assigned `Cluster cluster = new Cluster(1);` in example code

Comment: @maliks It was just as an example. I don't know what properties of clusters and clustermembers you're about to use.

Comment: @RenéVogt I have added an updated `C# Method` as an addendum, _can you please have a look at that method?_ whereas I have commented the difficult parts in the method to implement the logic

Comment: @RenéVogt I hope you are having a look at that.......still waiting for your response

Comment: @RenéVogt Its ok...so here in the meanwhile I would try it by using a `Dictionary<int, List<ClusterMember>` inside `Cluster` class

Comment: @RenéVogt haven't you looked at it?

Answer (score 2):

As is already mentioned. You can simply use a list. The bottom code example shows how to create the list type you need and how you add and access values in that list.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Creating a list of lists that contains integers
        List<List<int>> clusters = new List<List<int>>();
        //each list in the above list consists of a list of integers. So we need to add list of integers to that list
        List<int> row = new List<int>();
        //now we add integers to the list
        row.Add(1); row.Add(2); row.Add(3); row.Add(4);
        //Now we add the list of integers to the list of lists of integers
        clusters.Add(row);

        foreach(List<int> rows in clusters)
        {
            foreach(int num in rows)
            {
               System.Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("number of rows: {0}", clusters.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("number of elements in the first row: {0}", clusters[0].Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and concise example.

Comment: @Psioniax this is not what I asked for, please

Comment: @maliks This is exactly what you asked for. You can dynamically add and remove members of each list without defining a finite size.of either lists. Also Rene shows the exact same thing except he has defined a ClusterMember class. He even tells you how to get the cluster count and member count. Which can be done in the exact same way using my example. Maybe you should consider editing your post and tell us what you're exactly trying to exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a list of lists;

```
List<List<int>> clusters;
```

See this answer on another question for more info and also how to make it into a more generic class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596563/6065552

Comment: With one cluster int and one or more membership ints, maybe something like this would be better ... var clusterMembership = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

Comment: @Marc as it is a `Dictionary` can I remove and insert in it? As both `cluster int` and `clusterMembership int` both will be of single value, for instance _cluster 1 has 2 members, cluster 3 has 4 members...._, so it'll get changed in different iterations i.e. `clusterMembership`

Comment: To add you would use clusterMembership.Add(123, new List<int> { 456, 789 });. And if you wanted to remove the 123 cluster you would use clusterMembership.Remove(123);. If you want to add a membership to the cluster you would use clusterMembership[123].Add(444);. And to remove a membership from a cluster you would use clusterMembership[123].Remove(456);.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in a list which has keyvaluepair items. 
Or use Dictionary

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>()

Dictionary<int,int>();
```

so you can add new keyvaluepair for each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clusterMembership = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        //Add cluster 123 and assign a member count of 4
        clusterMembership.Add(123, 4);

        //Change member count for cluster 123 to 5
        clusterMembership[123] = 5;

        //Remove cluster 123
        clusterMembership.Remove(123);

        //Get the number of clusters in the dictionary
        var count = clusterMembership.Count;

        //Iterate through the dictionary
        foreach(var clusterKey in clusterMembership.Keys)
        {
            var memberCount = clusterMembership[clusterKey];
        }
    }
```