# c# Updating arrays in a dictionary and tuple in a loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, dictionary, tuples

I'm relatively new to C#, so your pardon for asking a question if posed before.

I need to populate the elements of arrays (e.g., double[]) 'on the fly' in a loop.  I know the maximum array length, but not the individual array values until run-time.

I have this code which initializes the Dictionary which contains a Tuple of arrays.  Given the allocation of the arrays in the tuple with empty slots, how do I add a double or string to the appropriate array in the tuple as the data are generated?

I demark my question below in the code.

```
public void Execute(SceneNode Parent)
{
    int maxAircraft = 10000;
    string vehicleState = "";
    double vehicleAlt;
    double vehicleVR;
    double vehicleTime;
    Dictionary<string, Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>> flightData
            = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>>(maxAircraft);

     //initializes flight state data dictionaries
     // flightList is a string[] already populated
     flightData = initializeFlightData(flightList, maxRecordCount);

//let's say that we start obtaining data for each entry in the dictionary
    foreach( var item in flightData )
    {
        //get the current values for the vehicle item at this time
        vehicleState = getVehicleStateMethod( item );
        vehicleAlt = getVehicleAltMethod( item );
        vehicleVR = getVehicleVrMethod( item );
        vehicleTime = getVehicleTimeMethod( item );
        var thisFlightData = flightData[aircraftName] as Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>; 
        //------------------------------------------------------

        ***// Question: how do I progressively add the values (vehicle*)
        // to each respective array such that the arrays are updated
        // (e.g., new value at bottom) with each new set of values?
        //------------------------------------------------------***

    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
private Dictionary<string, Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>> initializeFlightData(string[] flightList, int maxRecordCount)
{
//values for the arrays are unknown at this point
    double[] dt = new double[maxRecordCount];
    double[] vr = new double[maxRecordCount];
    double[] FL = new double[maxRecordCount];
    string[] altState = new string[maxRecordCount];
    var flightStateData = new Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>(dt, vr, FL, altState);

    Dictionary<string, Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>> flightData 
      = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>>(flightList.Count());
    for (int i = 0; i < flightList.Count(); i++)
    {
        flightData.Add(flightList[i], flightStateData);
    }
    return flightData;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't use Tuple, don't use arrays. Use a List of a class. The list can be resized at need, and the class can have named properties which describe their meaning, instead of `Item1` etc. This code as you have it is far too cryptic to work with. Also, using x number of parallel arrays/lists is much less usable than one list of a class with x number of properties.

Comment: OP, are you coming from a C or C++ background by any chance? It has nothing to do with your question but it would explain your fondness for arrays.

Comment: Adding to @EdPlunkett - Better to define a class which has as its properties a `List<double>`, another `List<double>`, and so on. One reason is that you can give those properties names, and then the thing in the dictionary is much less confusing. We can look at the dictionary without having to try to comprehend the thing in the dictionary at the same time. Longer variable names are a good idea too. It works the same but just makes it easier on the brain. If too much is confusing all at once then the brain has to work much harder to process it.

Comment: I'm fine with dropping the Tuple construct.  I like arrays because of my Matlab background, esp. cell arrays.  To reply to Steve H., you are saying that my dictionary should be like Dictionary<string, List<double, double, double, string>> with the *.Add method later?  As noted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596530/multi-dimensional-arraylist-or-list-in-c.

Comment: @BenjaminLevy a `List<T>` only takes one type argument. So you need to create a class that has properties for each of those values, or a class with multiple lists (whichever makes more sense in your context).

Comment: Did you mean Scott H? What I'm saying is just to replace the `Tuple<lots of arrays of double>` with a class. Now your dictionary is `Dictionary<string,YourClass>`. If you need to change the properties of that class you can do it in one place. And it's easier to read and understand than `Dictionary<string, Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>>`.  When you look at the `Dictionary` you don't need to see all of those details about the object stored in it. It works the same, but it keeps you from having to see so much information in once place.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, create an index variable and use `.Item1`, `.Item2`, etc. Like so

```
int index = 0;
foreach( var item in flightData )
{
    //get the current values for the vehicle item at this time
    vehicleState = getVehicleStateMethod( item );
    vehicleAlt = getVehicleAltMethod( item );
    vehicleVR = getVehicleVrMethod( item );
    vehicleTime = getVehicleTimeMethod( item );
    var thisFlightData = flightData[aircraftName] as Tuple<double[], double[], double[], string[]>; 
    //------------------------------------------------------

    ***// Question: how do I progressively add the values (vehicle*)
    // to each respective array such that the arrays are updated
    // (e.g., new value at bottom) with each new set of values?
    //------------------------------------------------------***
    thisFlightData.Item1[index] = // whatever
    // repeat for each array
    index++;
}
```

However, this is a brittle solution that I don't think you're going to want in the long run. Create a class with meaningful names for each array. And better yet, as @EdPlunkett commented, use lists instead and just add each new item to the end of the appropriate list.

Also note that you don't need to cast the Tuple after retrieving it from your dictionary.

Comment: I am obliged to you all.  I'm just creating a prototype; the computer programming team will know that it is brittle.  Your point is well-taken.